# move inline image to very first place in text using css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this code:

```
<div>
    this is text and this text and also <p>this paragraph</p> and the image <img src="the_image.jpg"> and the text.
</div>
```

I want to show the image at very first place of `div`, using css (Something like the float consept, except that here the image is inline whithin the text and not a sibling to it.)

**NOTE**
I can not move the image to the first, non-programatically.

Comment: May I ask why you cannot move the image "non-programmatically" ?

Comment: @AthanasiosEmmanouilidis good question. I have 1000 post, per day that have this problem. I have two solutions:1- parse it using php libxml (DomDocument) and move the image to very first place or 2- use css to just show it there (I dont know if the later is possible)

Comment: You should still be able to do this using float, unless I misunderstand what you are asking? See example: http://jsfiddle.net/2NgJm/

Comment: @Blake Mann. Thanks for your response. I removed many parts of div, due to simplicity. actually the div has so many tags like paragraphs, etc. in it and I just want the image at very first

Comment: do the images all have the same size?

Comment: @web-tiki, No they vary. the content is a news item, and it may have some jpg images

Comment: @Arash well this won't be possible with CSS alone then you'll have to use floats or go for a JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you said, you cannot mess up with the html markup. One way to do what you want, with pure css, I think would be to hide the actual image tag, and add the image to the beggining of the div using the `:before` pseudo and `content`.

```
div:before {
    content: url('the_image.jpg');
}

div img {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C3nmU/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I dont have url of the image, as I have plenty of this divs, every day. I just know that it is an image `<img>`